# Why does list( ) and tuple( ) expand a string into separate characters in python whereas [ ... ] and ( ... , ) do not

Tags: python, list, tuples

See the following:

```py
In [1]: list('hi')
Out[1]: ['h', 'i']

In [2]: ['hi']
Out[2]: ['hi']

In [3]: tuple('hi')
Out[3]: ('h', 'i')

In [4]: ('hi',)
Out[4]: ('hi',)
```

How is this behaviour to be explained / understood though?

Looking at the output of `dis.dis` (something I'm not really familiar with), we have:

```py
In [8]: dis.dis('list("hello")')
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (list)
              2 LOAD_CONST               0 ('hello')
              4 CALL_FUNCTION            1
              6 RETURN_VALUE

In [9]: dis.dis('["hello"]')
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 ('hello')
              2 BUILD_LIST               1
              4 RETURN_VALUE

In [10]: dis.dis('tuple("hello")')
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (tuple)
              2 LOAD_CONST               0 ('hello')
              4 CALL_FUNCTION            1
              6 RETURN_VALUE

In [11]: dis.dis('("hello",)')
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (('hello',))
              2 RETURN_VALUE
```

The difference being `LOAD_NAME` and `CALL_FUNCTION` for each of these.

I looked at the documentation for list function here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-list , and then here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-list . From the second page is:

> If iterable is already a list, a copy is made and returned, similar to iterable[:]. For example, `list('abc')` returns `['a', 'b', 'c']` and `list( (1, 2, 3) )` returns [`1, 2, 3]`.

I don't feel that this really answers my question though, about why `[ hi ] -> ['hi']` and `list('hi') -> ['h','i']`.

I make regular use of this functionality, and perhaps it's just a "definition" and there's nothing to be understood, but after trying to find out the reasoning I was unable to.

Answer (score 2):

Python strings are iterable objects.
By providing an iterable object to `list(...)` or `tuple(...)` you are implicitly telling the interpreter something like "turn this iterable into a list/tuple", so in the case of a string it would be a list/tuple of all the characters in the provided.

`[...]` and `(...,)` are literals that explicitly state the list/tuple members.

Answer (score 0):

The `[...]` and `(...,)` syntax is for literals, while `list(...)` and `tuple(...)` create a list/tuple from an iterable.

Since strings are iterable (they yield their characters) you get `["H", "i"]` instead of `["Hi"]`.